# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/metamodel/source/annotations/JPADotNames Error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am a complete newbie in springboot and hibernate and jpa. I posted a question earlier but somehow or the other solved that but now I am stuck at another huge error.

I was trying to have two separate tables from a same database. Two have their own model as well as repository classes. The code is running fluently when there is just a single table being processed but when two tables are being processed this error is causing:

```
2019-06-16 00:38:12.178  INFO 14868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-06-16 00:38:12.180  INFO 14868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-06-16 00:38:12.181  INFO 14868 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-06-16 00:38:12.226  WARN 14868 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/metamodel/source/annotations/JPADotNames
Sun Jun 16 00:38:12 IST 2019 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...  goes on and on....
```

applications.yml

```
spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema
    username: root
    password: user
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:

    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.techprimers.db</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-mysqldb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-cleardb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

InterestDao.java  - Dao Class 1

```
package com.techprimers.db.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.techprimers.db.model.Interest;
import com.techprimers.db.repository.InterestRepository;

@Service
public class InterestDao{


    @Autowired
    InterestRepository interrepo;

    public Interest findOne(String token) {
        return interrepo.findOne(token);
    }

}
```

usersdao.java - Dao Class 2

```
package com.techprimers.db.dao;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.techprimers.db.model.Users;
import com.techprimers.db.repository.UsersRepository;

@Service
public class userdao {


    @Autowired
    UsersRepository userrepo;

    public Users findOne(String token) {
        return userrepo.findOne(token);
    }



}
```

Interest.java - Model Class 1

```
package com.techprimers.db.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name="hb_interest")
public class Interest{

    @Column(name="ticket_no")
    private String ticket_no;

    @Column(name="hb_type")    
    private String hb_type;

    @Column(name="hb_unit_hints")
    private String hb_unit_hints;

    @Column(name="hb_value")
    private float hb_value;

    public Interest() {
    }



    //getters and setters......


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "\"ticket_no\":" +"\"" + ticket_no + "\""+"," +
                "\"Genre\":" +"\""+ hb_type + "\""+","+
                "\"Powers\":"+"\"" + hb_unit_hints +"\""+
                "\"Characters_No\":"+"\"" + hb_value +"\""+
                '}';
    }


}
```

Users.java   Model class 2

```
package com.techprimers.db.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
public class Users {


    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "token_id")
    private String teamName;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Integer salary;

    public Users() {
    }

  //getters and setters....


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "\"id\":" +"\"" + id + "\""+"," +
                "\"value\":" +"\""+ name + "\""+","+
                "\"Anime\":"+"\"" + teamName +"\""+
                '}';
    }

}
```

InterestRepository.java

```
package com.techprimers.db.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.techprimers.db.model.Interest;



public interface InterestRepository extends JpaRepository<Interest, String> {

}
```

UsersRepository.java

```
package com.techprimers.db.repository;

import com.techprimers.db.model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {
}
```

UsersResource.java  The Controller Class

```
package com.techprimers.db.resource;

import com.techprimers.db.dao.InterestDao;
import com.techprimers.db.dao.userdao;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class UsersResource {

    @Autowired
    userdao userDao;
    InterestDao interdao;

    @Autowired
    ProcessData pd;

     @GetMapping("/persons")
     public JSONObject loadPersons(@RequestParam("access_token") String access_token) throws  ParseException{
        String decode_token = pd.testDecodeJWT(access_token); // Function to decode the access token
        String token = pd.jsondata(decode_token);//Fetch the token from the decoded access token
        String data= userDao.findOne(token).toString();//Convert the response data from table 1 to JSON String.
        String med= interdao.findOne(token).toString();//Convert the response data from table 2 to JSON String

//Converting JSON String to JSON Objects
        JSONObject  json_data=pd.responseData(data);
        JSONObject  json_med=pd.responseData(med);
//Was only trying to return the 1st table data but the code stopped working.
        return json_data;
     }


}
```

I don't know the cause of the error .I have added external jars of hibernate but that also didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>` dependencies are not needed in this case. And please please post your project structure and  domain class.

Comment: @AvijitBarua Well I cannot post each and every code in here. I am using two model classes and two JpaRepositories to access data from two tables. But that is not working.    And if I don't add those dependencies another error is coming related to commons annotations.

Comment: @Why can't you post your code ? There are no limitation in posting whole code !!

Comment: @AvijitBarua  Done . You can check it now. I am a complete newbie so I followed some youtube tutorials to reach to this spot . I don't have much idea how JPA and mysql works and please do ignore the names , this is just a type of test api.

Comment: You should not have `JSONObject` as `return type` in you controller. Use `POJO` or send as `JSONString`. It will be converted to JSONObject in client side.
Moreover, for one table which code block you added causes the issue? For two, can you say upto which points it works?

Comment: @user404 For the 1st table it is working completely and giving me expected data . As of the second table a NullPointerException is showing. I am working towards that. So lets see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not specify the Hibernate version that is different from Spring Boot.

Spring Boot uses : 5.0.12.Final

Remove

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```